# How to get a proper pdf-a document

Tags: pdf-a

I tried VERA https://verapdf.org/home/#validation for testing pdf-a format and I get these errors:

```
Rule    Status
Specification: ISO 19005-2:2011, Clause: 6.2.11.4, Test number: 1   
The font programs for all fonts used for rendering within a conforming file shall be embedded within that file, as defined in ISO 32000-1:2008, 9.9.    Failed
14 occurrences  Show


Specification: ISO 19005-2:2011, Clause: 6.2.8, Test number: 3  
If an Image dictionary contains the Interpolate key, its value shall be false. For an inline image, the I key shall have a value of false.  Failed
1 occurrences   Show


Specification: ISO 19005-2:2011, Clause: 6.2.11.7, Test number: 1   
The Font dictionary of all fonts shall define the map of all used character codes to Unicode values, either via a ToUnicode entry, or other mechanisms as defined in ISO 19005-2, 6.2.11.7.2.   Failed
1 occurrences
```

How to correct it please? Thank you

Comment: Please show a minimal compilable code example (MWE) to reproduce these warnings.

Comment: I found out that this command makes problem:  `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize$\blacksquare$} `

Comment: Would it be possible to show a full example document with this command that fails the validation and produces the messages shown in the question?